# ncurses-like based applications won't work in emacs terminals

Tags: ansi-term, term, ubuntu, multi-term

No *curses applications (like top, htop, Linux kernel's `make menuconfig` and others) will work under emacs' different terms. However, the only one which seems to work is `git add -i`

It behaves the same under term, multi-term and ansi-term: output a lot of messy garbage. It does the same when not splitting frames and I reproduced this behavior without any configuration (moved .emacs and .emacs.d somewhere else).

I included a screenshot of when I tried a `make menuconfig` in Linux kernel's base directory.

I am running `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-04-17 on lgw01-04, modified by Debian` in GUI on Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there a way of fixing this ? Is it just an isolated bug or related to emacs in general ?

[image]

Comment: FYI I have no issues running `top` and `htop` under `ansi-term` in Emacs 24.5. Possibly your issues are on account of missing `eterm-color` terminfo? I believe `apt-get install ncurses-term` on Debian systems should install this for you; or you can copy (or symlink) the `eterm-color` and `eterm-color.ti` files from the `/usr/share/emacs/xx.x/etc/e` directory to a `~/.terminfo/e/` directory, or system-wide at `/usr/share/terminfo/e/`.

Comment: I installed ncurses-term with no results.
Then I tried to move `/usr/share/emacs/24.5/etc/e/eterm-color*` to `/usr/share/terminfo/e/` without success. Also tried to move them to `~/.terminfo/e/` without a change.
Also removed original eterm-color from `/usr/share/terminfo/e/` still without a change.
Also tried to do the opposite and moved `/usr/share/terminfo/e/eterm-color` to `/usr/share/emacs/xx.x/etc/e/` but that didn't work. 
Do I need to reboot, login/logout, use another command to refresh some cache or activate these configs ?

Comment: I don't think so. You could try it, but I'm guessing this wasn't actually the source of the problem (but nevertheless a good thing to have in place, and to keep in mind in general for any remote hosts you connect to).

Answer (score -1):

Reddit just had a discussion on terminals. Try this?

```
(setq eshell-visual-commands 
      (cons eshell-visual-commands '("el" "elinks" "htop" "less" "ssh" "tmux" "top" "mbsync" "docker" "docker-compose"))
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/4nwow3/emacs_shell_configuration_for_2016/d48n3t3

Comment: this only affects eshell, which is is not a terminal at all